# Battery light comes on. I disconnect neg on battery and vehicle still runs. Why is light coming on?

Tags: chevrolet

2000 Chevrolet truck 4x4 1500 Silverado

Answer (score 2):

The battery light could be coming on due to a loose / broken wire or short while the alternator is still charging keeping the engine running.

However I suggest that you should **not** disconnect the battery when the engine is running as it is possible to damage the alternator - an expensive repair...

There are people who will tell "I always check charging systems like that" and others, like me, who say yes and we get to sell you a new alternator when it goes wrong...

A properly working alternator will charge between 13.8 to 15.2 volts - depending on the type of charging profile it uses (my car **does** go up to 15.2 Volts and I have checked it with a quality meter).

Comment: It's not just the alternator that's at danger. Without the buffering of the battery, all electrical systems of the car are at danger.